# I can't seem to access bios to enable turbo boost in my Windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: boot, laptop, windows-8.1, bios, shutdown

As I have addressed in the title, I’m unable to access BIOS in my Windows 8.1 (pro) 64-bit version so that I can't turn on turbo boost.

The windows is too fast at start up, I can’t even see any key to access BIOS except for <kbd>Esc</kbd> or get enough time to try and press every possible BIOS key (<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd> etc)

I have tried the solutions from various sites which don't work (Listed below)

1. I tried pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to access startup menu, from which I think I may be able to access the BIOS setup, but the key doesn't work (<kbd>Esc</kbd> key works after getting to desktop though)
2. To fix the above (<kbd>Esc</kbd> key) problem I was told to shutdown my laptop and remove the battery then hold down peer button for 30seconds followed by reinserting the battery after 10minutes
3. I tried disabling fast startup of windows through power options --> choose what power buttons do --> disable fast start up
4. Again tried disabling fast start up by shutdown /s /t 0 shortcut method and also by running a .bat file downloaded from the internet.
5. I tried accessing by advanced start up in which I was told to select the uefi firmware settings which is not found in the advanced start up menu.
6. Also I was told to shutdown by using shift + shutdown option and windows key + x + shutdown option to do a full shutdown so that I may get enough time to press <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd> or Delete key to access BIOS

Can you guys suggest me a different method to access BIOS or to fix the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key?

Comment: If you don't know which key press brings up the BIOS menu, don't try to press all the options: instead, press one of the keys repeatedly during the boot process - you should be able to manage around 5 presses per second. Try <kbd>F2</kbd> first; if that doesn't catch it, reboot and try <kbd>Del</kbd>; if it still doesn't work, try each of the other keys you suggest on a separate reboot. This is how I managed to get in.

Comment: access the advanced startup option, here you should have an entry to access the firmware: http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/16535d1360705987-uefi-firmware-settings-boot-inside-windows-8-a-uefi-3.jpg http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/20256-uefi-firmware-settings-boot-inside-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @magicandre1981, that's the way I tried to get into firmware settings (Listed in the question, refer to 5), anyway I have found a solution. I tried holding my laptop's power button to shutdown, and restarted my computer by pressing it. Then the Esc key leads me to BIOS via startup options. If that doesn't work download TDSkiller from Kasperky or rootkit remover from McAfee to remove the rootkit virus which prevents the Esc key from from functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Press Left shift together with RESTART button

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: We prefer answers that have some reference links.